# PowerShell regex for encoding API filter into a URL

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string that needs to be encoded for a URL, so I have to replace some instances of certain characters.

For example:

```
filter=prop1:"folder1/folder2",prop2>:"string & string",prop3~"d:d"
```

In this example, "filter=" and each property name and operator ("prop1:", "prop2>:", and "prop3~") need to stay. The forward slash, ampersand, space, and the last colon (in d:d) need to be replaced with %2F, %26, %20 and %3A

```
filter=prop1:"folder1%2Ffolder2",prop2>:"string%20%26%20string",prop3~"d%3Ad"
```

With this application, the properties and values can be separated by:

```
>:
<:
>
<
!:
:
~
!~
```

The characters I want to replace in each pair's "value" section:

```
&
$
+
,
/
:
;
=
?
@
space
"
<
>
#
%
{
}
|
\
^
~
[
]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help get you somewhere.

```
$test = 'filter=prop1:"folder1/folder2",prop2>:"string & string",prop3~"d:d"'
$pattern = '(?:>:|<:|:|>|<|!:|:|~|!~)(?:")(.*?)(?:")'
$regex = [Regex]::new($pattern)
$regex.Matches($test) | ForEach-Object {
    $test = $test -replace ([regex]::Escape($_.Groups[1].value)), ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Groups[1].value))
}
$test

# Output
filter=prop1:"folder1%2Ffolder2",prop2>:"string%20%26%20string",prop3~"d%3Ad"
```

Comment: Amazing! I have never heard of EscapeDataString. That's great, thanks.